# Swift 3 ternary operator with optional arguments

Tags: swift3, ternary-operator, optional-arguments

Whats was happened with the arguments of ternary operator in Swift 3?
Are they not optional now?
Is it possible to write code like this one:

```
let a = true ? nil : ""
```

Comment: `let a: String? = true ? nil : ""` is the identical substitute; which could be an answer to your concern, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what's wrong with type inference in Swift 3? Is it feature?

Comment: there is no _'type-interference'_ here at all. what kinda interference do you see?

Comment: Inference, dude, type inference. I surprised that now I need to set type explicitly.

Comment: Looks like the same problem as filed in [SR-2336](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2336), where the compiler is unable to infer that having `nil` and some type `T` as inputs for the ternary conditional operator should result in type `T?`.

Comment: `let a = true ? String?.none : ""` is another option.

Comment: `let a = true ? nil : ""` compiles and infers `a` to be of type `Optional<String>` as expected at IBM Sandbox, Swift 3.0. Is this not the case for XCode8 w/ Swift 3?

Comment: Thanks everybody! This issue is in Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) - `Playground execution failed: error: Swift3.playground:1:28: error: result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '_' and 'String'
let a: String = true ? nil : ""`